# Holomorphic function $f$ in $D$ which is not holomorphically extendible across any point in $\partial D$.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Prove that for any domain $D\subset \mathbb{C}$, there is a holomorphic function $f$ in $D$ which is not holomorphically extendible across any point in $\partial D$.

So, I was able to prove this for a particular point $z_0\in \partial D$. Because there is a sequence $\{z_n\}\subset D$ that converges to $z_0$. Since $\{z_n\}$ has no accumulation point in $D$ by Weierstrass product theorem there is a holomorphic function $f$ on $D$ such that all of its zeros are $z_n$'s. Since zeros of a holomorphic function is a discrete set $f$ cannot be holomorphically extendible across $z_0$.

Now here I have to find an $f$ that cannot be holomorphically extendible not only across $z_0$ but also across "any" point on $\partial D$. But I don't see a way to modify my proof for it. In particular, how could I find a sequence of points such that every boundary point is a limit point of it?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of the other answer can be extended. For each $z\in\partial D$, there is a sequence $\{u_n(z)\}\subset D$ such that $u_n(z)\to z$. Now take a countable set $A\subset\partial D$ which is dense in $\partial D$ and let $\{z_n\}$ be an enumeration of $A$. The set $\{u_n(z_k):n,k\in\mathbb N\}$ is also countable, so let $\{\omega_n\}$ be an enumeration. What are the limit points of this sequence?