# Every holomorphic function defined by power series with radius of convergence $1$ must have a point on $|z|=1$ beyond which $f$ cannot be extended.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, analytic-continuation

I am sorry if the title of this post is confusing, feel free to edit it. My question is as follows:

I am working on an exercise stated as follows:

> Let $\mathcal{E}$ be the set of holomorphic functions $f(z)$ defined as power series $f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}z^{n}$ with radius of convergence equal to $1$. Denoting $C$ to the unit circle, and for $f\in\mathcal{E}$, we define $$S(f):=\{z\in C:\ f\ \text{cannot be extended as a holomorphic function in a neighborhood of}\ z\}.$$
>
> 1. Show that $S(f)$ is closed and non-empty.
> 2. For $z_{0}\in C$, find an example such that $S(f)=\{z_{0}\}$.

I found a similar post here: [Holomorphic function $f$ in $D$ which is not holomorphically extendible across any point in $\partial D$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2348334/holomorphic-function-f-in-d-which-is-not-holomorphically-extendible-across-a)

---

I tried to mimic the proof in the above post. As $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ is sequentially compact, for any $z\in C$, there exists a sequence $\{z_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in $\mathbb{D}$ that converges to $z$. We know recall

> [Weierstrass Theorem on Zeros of Holomorphic Functions] Assume $V$ is a proper open set of the Riemann Sphere $\mathbb{C}_{\infty}$, and let $A\subset V$ be a set that has no accumulation point in $V$. Then, there exists a function $f$ holomorphic on $V$ such that the set of zeros $Z(f)$ is exactly $A$, counting the multiplicities.

In our case, $V=\mathbb{D}$ and $A=\{z_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$. Note that the limit point of $A$ is on $\partial D$, so $A$ has no accumulation point in $\mathbb{D}$. Hence, by the theorem, there exists a holomorphic function $g$ in $\mathbb{D}$ such that $g(z_{n})=0$ for all $z_{n}\in A$.

But then I don't know how to proceed. The original post said that since the zeros are isolated, then we cannot extend beyond $z\in C$. I don't quite follow this argument.

Also, my proof seems backward... As saulspatz suggested, $f$ is given, and I need to show that there exists $z\in C$ such that $f$ cannot be analytically continued.

---

I don't quite know how to prove the set is closed.

I also don't really know how to find the example for $2$. I took a look at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10831/example-of-continuous-function-that-is-analytic-on-the-interior-but-cannot-be-an, but did not find a proper example.

Thanks for any help!

---

**Edit 1: Proof of Q1 part 1**

Thanks to Conrad's suggestion, we show $C\setminus S(f)$ open. To show this, we show that for any $z\in C\setminus S(f)$, there exists $r=r(z)>0$ such that $D(z,r)\cap C\subset C\setminus S(f)$.

Indeed, let $z\in C\setminus S(f)$, i.e. $f$ can be analytically continued around $z$. Hence, there exists $r=r(z)>0$ such that there exists a holomorphic function $g$ on $D(z,r)$ such that $g=f$ on $D(z,r)\cap D$.

Let $z_{0}\in D(z,r)\cap C$, take $r_{0}>0$ such that $D(z_{0}, r_{0})\subsetneq D(z,r)$. Then, it is clear that $g$ is holomorphic on $D(z_{0}, r_{0})$ and $f=g$ on $D(z_{0}, r_{0})\cap\mathbb{D}\cap D(z,r)\cap\mathbb{D}$.

Hence, $f$ has an analytic continuation around $z_{0}$. This means that $z_{0}\in C\setminus S(f)\implies D(z,r)\cap C\subset C\setminus S(f)$.

We are done

---

**Edit 2: Example for Q2.**

Taking $z_{0}\in C$, i.e. $|z_{0}|=1$ and consider the series $$f(z):=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\Bigg(\dfrac{1}{z_{0}}\Bigg)^{n+1}z^{n}.$$ The radius of convergence is $$R:=\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\Bigg|\dfrac{1}{z_{0}}\Bigg|^{\frac{n+1}{n}}=1.$$

So in $\mathbb{D}$, we have $$f(z)=\dfrac{1}{z_{0}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\Bigg(\dfrac{z}{z_{0}}\Bigg)^{n}=\dfrac{1}{z_{0}-z}.$$

Note that the function $h(z):=\frac{1}{z_{0}-z}$ is holomorphic everywhere on $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ except at $z_{0}$.

But $h(z)$ is not bounded around $z_{0}$ so by Riemann's theorem on removable singularity that $z_{0}$ is not removable.

Hence, we have $g$ analytic on $\overline{\mathbb{D}}\setminus\{z_{0}\}$ and $f=g$ on $\mathbb{D}$, and thus $f$ has an analytic continuation from $\mathbb{D}$ to $C$, except at the point $z_{0}$.

$S(f)=\{z_{0}\}$.

---

**Edit 3:**

Okay I proved that $S(f)$ is non-empty, see my own answer of the question below.

Comment: $f\equiv 0$ is an obvious counter-example to (1).

Comment: It seems unlikely you mean to ask exactly what you ask here. But since you do ask explicitly, more than once: No, $f(z)=0$ gives an example of a function holomorphic in the disk that can be continued past _any_ boundary point.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yeah... I will edit the post. I think we should prove that given any $z\in C$, there exists a holomorphic function such that $f$ cannot be analytically continued beyond it.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy right.. thanks for the example. I will edit the post

Comment: They obviously meant to say that the radius of convergence is $1$, as otherwise the statement is false.  They want you to show that there is a point $z$ on the circle, so that $f$ cannot be continued to a neighborhood of $z$.  ($f$ is given, you have to show the existence of $z$.)  Then they want you to show that the set of all such points $z$ is closed.  Finally, they want you to give an example of a function $f$ such that there is exactly on such $z$.

Comment: @saulspatz okay, let me state the whole exercise completely. I think you are right..

Comment: note that $C-S(f)$ is open since if the function is extendable at a point, it is obviously erxtendable near by; this gives $S(f)$ closed, while non-empty follows by compacity (if $f$ extendable at each point, cover the circle by finitely many open neighborhoods where $f$ extendable and their union plus the open disc obviously contains a slightly larger disc, hence radius convergence not $1$); rotating $\sum z^n$ should give point 2

Comment: @Conrad sorry for the late reply. Thank you so much for the suggestion. I have proved the first part of Q1, and edited the post. However, I had a hard time to formalize the second part of Q1. So we suppose $S(f)$ is empty, then for each $z\in C$, there exists $r=r(z)>0$ such that $f$ can be analytically continued to $D(z,r)$. We consider $\Big(\bigcup_{z\in C}D(z,r)\Big)\cup \mathbb{D}$ which is an open cover of $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$.

Comment: @Conrad But $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ is compact, so we get a finite sub cover $D(z_{1}, r_{1}),\cdots, D(z_{n},r_{n})$ so that $C\subset\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}D(z_{k}, r_{k})$. But then I don't know how to proceed to argue that the radius of convergence of $f(z)$ is bigger than one formally.

Comment: @Conrad Okay, so I set $\delta:=\min_{i}r_{i}$, and define $g(z)=f_{i}(z) \ \text{if}\ z\in B(z_{i}, r_{i})$ so that the function $h(z)$ defined by $h(z)=f(z)$ for $z\in\mathbb{D}$ and $h(z)=g(z)$ for $z\in D(0,1+\delta)\setminus\mathbb{D}$ is analytic on $D(0,1+\delta)$. Therefore, the power series of $g(z)$ $$g(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_{n}z^{n}$$ converges with a radius of convergence $1+\delta$. But I don't know how to go back to $f(z)$.

Comment: the function to consider is $\sum a_nz^n$ which then converges on $D(0,1+c)$ (here one has to be careful as $\delta=\min r_i$ may not quite work - draw a picture to see why, but there is some $c$ that works considering the boundary of $D(0,1) \cup B(z_i, r_i)$ which is compact and at a positive distance, though maybe smaller than $\delta$ - from the unit circle ) - more formally if $g$ is as in the previous comment, $g-f$ coincide on the unit disc, hence $a_n=b_n$ by the identity principle

Comment: @Conrad I am sorry what I meant should be $$h(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_{n}z^{n},$$ and you mean my construction is correct, but I need to be careful about the radius of convergence, which should be some $1+c$ for $c<\delta$. And then $h-f$ and $g$ coincide on the unit circle? I am sorry for my confusion here.

Comment: $h-f$ is zero on the unit disc by definition, so $\sum (a_n-b_n)z^n=0$ there hence $a_n=b_n$

Comment: @Conrad okay I think I should clam down and take a while to think about your suggestion. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Conrad Thanks for the help! I proved it, and just answered my own post. Now everything is clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, for other proofs, please see the edit of my post. I am answering my own question to prove that $S(f)\neq\varnothing$.

Suppose $S(f)=\varnothing$, then all the points on $C$ can be analytically continued to for $f$. So for each $z\in C$, we have $D(z,r)$ for $f$ to have the analytic continuation.

Then, as $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ is compact, the covering $\Big(\bigcup_{z\in C}D(z,r)\Big)\cup\mathbb{D}$ gives us finite sub cover $\{D(z_{i}, r_{i})\}_{i=1}^{N}$.

We define $\epsilon:=\min_{i}r_{i}$, and note that this finite sub-cover will cover the annulus $D(0,1+\epsilon)\setminus\mathbb{D}$.

Define $f_{i}$ to be the corresponding analytic continuation of $f$ to $D(z_{i}, r_{i})$. Then, for each $z$ in this annulus, we define $$g(z)=f_{i}(z)$$ if $z\in D(z_{i}, r_{i})$. This is well-defined since every point in the annulus is in at least one covering ball, and in the intersection of two balls, $f_{i}(z)=f=f_{j}(z)$ by the analytic continuation.

Now, define $h(z)=f(z)$ for $z\in\mathbb{D}$ and $h(z)=g(z)$ for $z$ in annulus.

It follows that $h(z)$ is holomorphic in $D(0,1+c)$ for some $c<\epsilon$. So it has a power expansion $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_{n}z^{n}$, but this will also represent $f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}z^{n}$ inside $\mathbb{D}$, this forces $a_{n}=b_{n}$, so $f(z)$ has radius of convergence $1+c>1$, a contradiction.